# Java: Find a certain character and get substring

Tags: java, python, string

I have a string `4.9.14_05_29_16_21` and I need to get `4.9` only. The numbers vary so I can't simply get the first three elements of this char array. I have to find the right most `.` and substring it till there.

I'm from Python so I'll show Python approach to this.

```
def foobar(some_string):
    location = some_string.rfind('.')
    new_string = some_string[0:location]
    return new_string
```

How would I do this in Java?

Comment: If you did it with regular expressions, it'd be `(.*)\.[^.]`. And yes, I know that's not a full answer, hence comment. From what I can tell, there are a couple good answers already which... *sniff*... don't use regex at all.

Comment: @ParthianShot Regex is almost always the slowest solution. It should only be used if there are no other options.

Comment: @durron597 True. I just like it. And, in fairness, the really slow part can be done at compile-time with a lexer generator. Just... usually people don't bother.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`String#lastIndexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28int%29) and [`String#substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29):

```
int location = someString.lastIndexOf('.');
String newString = someString.substring(0, location);
```

Also note that I've assumed Java's naming convention (i.e. camelCase). If there can be cases where the input does not include a period, you can check if `location` is negative and include logic to deal with that case.

Comment: I hope there's a `.` in the input :) See my answer

Comment: @durron597 Based on the OP's Python code, I assumed that there would always be a `.`, but I made a note on the subject nonetheless.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the following methods:

- [`String.lastIndexOf(int ch)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28int%29) to get the index
- [`String.substring(int beginindex, int endindex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) to 
  extract the `String`.

Make sure to put an error check in if the string doesn't contain any `.`, i.e. `lastIndexOf` returns `-1`.

```
public String getBeforePeriod(String input) {
  int index = input.lastIndexOf('.');
  return index > -1 ? input.substring(0,index) : input;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use String.indexOf() method to provide one second argument to substring() method.
Here is a link to more info.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_indexof.htm